# I can't read route static data from child into parent

Tags: angular

I have a layout and I want to customize it based on some static data defined at the child routes level.

```
 const routes: Routes = [
 {
  path: '', 
  component: LayoutComponent,   
  children: [
      { path: '', component: GridComponent},           
      { path: 'buy', component: BuyComponent, data:{backButton:true,titleColor:'green'}},        
      { path: 'read', component: ReadComponent,  data:{backButton:false,titleColor:'blue'}}, 
      { path: 'watch', component: WatchComponent, data:{backButton:true,titleColor:'red'}},        
  ]
}];
```

I have here a solution example with what I need for an easy understanding of the problem:
[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uwa8uj?file=src%2Fpublic%2Flayout%2Flayout.component.ts)

I've defined the example as close as my real project is and that is why you will see also multiples modules and lazy load for some.

P.S. - I don't want the data into a service because is not dynamic, it is just some route configuration data.

Comment: If you have static data, can't you just maintain the data in a service or data store rather than passing through routes?

Comment: I don't want a service because is just static data, if it was dynamic, yes, would have made more sense to have it as a service. But it's absurd I can't have an easy way to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take the snapshot of the firstChild, this will allow you to access the properties

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout.component.css'],
})
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  showButton = true;
  customColor = 'blue';

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    router.events
      .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe((v: any) => {
        const data =
          this.route.firstChild &&
          this.route.firstChild.snapshot &&
          this.route.firstChild.snapshot.data;
        //this.route.children.forEach(c => c.data.subscribe(cd => console.log(cd, 'child data')));
        // I need to read the static data for the current path and setup the layout accordingly
        console.log(data);
        this.showButton = (data && data.backButton) || false;
        this.customColor = (data && data.titleColor) || 'blue';
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  getTitleStyles() {
    return {
      color: this.customColor,
    };
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mjszx5)

Comment: Thank u. I've spent 3 hours and search on internet and use stupid chat gpt for a solution.